# ASP.NET View Model / Identity Model

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working in MVC5/WebAPI using ASP.NET Identity, with a custom storage provider for my `UserStore`, custom `ApplicationUser` inheriting from `IdentityUser`, and a pretty expansive configuration in the project (both MVC5 and WebAPI endpoints in the same project).

I've been working on the user management/settings controller (`ManageController`), following the same principles the template projects use; however, with the additional fields I have in my `ApplicationUser`, it is getting to the point that my view model is starting to be a duplicate of the `ApplicationUser` class. I wanted someone to take a look at some of my code and let me know if they think the way I'm setting things up currently is appropriate, or if I am cluttering a view model with fields.

**ManageViewModels.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace Disco.Models
{
    public class IndexViewModel
    {        
        public string Email { get; set; }        
        public bool HasPassword { get; set; }
        public IList<UserLoginInfo> Logins { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactor { get; set; }
        public bool BrowserRemembered { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Handle { get; set;}
    }

    public class ManageLoginsViewModel
    {
        public IList<UserLoginInfo> CurrentLogins { get; set; }
        public IList<AuthenticationDescription> OtherLogins { get; set; }
    }

    public class FactorViewModel
    {
        public string Purpose { get; set; }
    }

    public class SetPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChangePasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddPhoneNumberViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerifyPhoneNumberViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConfigureTwoFactorViewModel
    {
        public string SelectedProvider { get; set; }
        public ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Providers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Schloss.AspNet.Identity.Neo4j
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        // @ handle / username
        public string Handle { get; set; }

        public string Picture { get; set; }

        public char Gender { get; set; }

        public string DeviceId { get; set; } // Most recently used mobile phone ID (iPhone, iPad, Android, etc)

        // Address
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZIPCode { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }

        // SignalR
        public HashSet<string> ConnectionIds { get; set; } // SignalR connections set (for handling multiple live sessions, propagation of push notifications)

        //public static string Labels { get { return "User"; } }

        // Helper Properties
        [JsonIgnore]
        public String FullName
        {
            get { return (FirstName + " " + LastName).Trim(); } // helper property to format user's full name
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            // Add custom user claims here

            return userIdentity;
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);

            // Add custom user claims here

            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
}
```

**ManageController.cs** (just the Index view)

```
//
        // GET: /Manage/Index
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
                : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was added."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was removed."
                : "";

            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            var model = new IndexViewModel
            {                
                Email = await UserManager.GetEmailAsync(userId),                
                HasPassword = await UserManager.HasPasswordAsync(userId),
                PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
                TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
                Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
                BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId),

                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                Picture = user.Picture,
                Handle = user.Handle
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### MergeController.cs

First off, I would use a switch on `message`. It's faster (though not by a lot) than ternary (`?:`) operators or `if` statements. Also, I would have each `UserManager` async method run at the same time. That is, save them to a `var` and then await each `var` in the `IndexViewModel`. (You may have to clean up syntax for that portion, I wrote it without the ASP.NET context.)

The idea behind moving the `await` keywords, is that it allows **all** the tasks to start before requesting data from them, so they can run in parallel. As it stands now, the programme will wait for `user` to run, then it will wait for `email` to run, etc. This way, it will get them all started, and then `await` what's left. (Though, again, I wrote it without the ASP.NET context, you may or may not be able to use that portion in that manner.)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess:
            ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your password has been changed.";
            break;
        case ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess:
            ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your password has been set.";
            break;
        case ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess:
            ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set.";
            break;
        case ManageMessageId.Error:
            ViewBag.StatusMessage = "An error has occurred.";
            break;
        case ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess:
            ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your phone number was added.";
            break;
        case ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess:
            ViewBag.StatusMessage = "Your phone number was removed.";
            break;
        default:
            ViewBag.StatusMessage = "";
            break;
    }

    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var userTask = UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    var email = UserManager.GetEmailAsync(userId);
    var hasPassword = UserManager.HasPasswordAsync(userId);
    var phoneNumber = UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId);
    var twoFactor = UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId);
    var logins = UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId);
    var browserRemembered = AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId);
    var user = await userTask;

    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        Email = await email,
        HasPassword = await hasPassword,
        PhoneNumber = await phoneNumber,
        TwoFactor = await twoFactor,
        Logins = await logins,
        BrowserRemembered = await browserRemembered,

        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,
        Picture = user.Picture,
        Handle = user.Handle
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

### ApplicationUser.cs

I can't see anything here that really needs help. There's not much going in so it's inherently clean.

### ManageViewModels.cs

Again, there's not much here so not a lot to optimize.

Overall, there's not a lot going on, so there's not a lot to optimize. Most of the optimizations that could be made are purely readability/maintenance, apart from the `await` keyword optimizations.

### IndexViewModel

Your initial concern was the `IndexViewModel`, which as far as I can see, doesn't require much work. (If you need all those properties for display, then so be it. Don't try cutting out properties if you **know** you need them, just because you think there are too many.)

You could possibly replace properties there that are duplicates of the `ApplicationUser`, and then store an `ApplicationUser` in it, and access the properties by `IndexViewModel.ApplicationUser.Property`. Though you can really only do that for the common properties.